# Unity facebook share button

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

When I posted my game made in Unity for Android yesterday, the share button worked perfectly, displaying every info I have put in. Today, however, it is showing only the title and the image thumb. Where is the problem as I haven't changed absolutely anything?

```
public void Share(){
        FB.ShareLink(
            contentTitle: "I scored " + GameController.instance.score + " on Flash Football. Can you beat my score?",
            contentURL: new System.Uri("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flash.football"),
            photoURL: new System.Uri("http://i.imgur.com/mQLDue5.png"),
            contentDescription: "Try to click the ball to score a point. It is harder than it looks. Click to learn more.",
            callback: OnShare);
    }

    private void OnShare(IShareResult result){
        if (result.Cancelled || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
            Debug.Log("Share error: " + result.Error);
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Error))
            Debug.Log(result.PostId);
        else
            Debug.Log("Success");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update Facebook SDK.
Facebook sometimes change all backhand calls, and that can cause a error.